# Differentiability of Wiener integral with respect to a parameter

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $f:[0,T]\times\Theta\to\mathbb R$ and let $\{B_t\}_{t\in [0,T]}$be a Brownian motion.

Consider the Wiener integral

$$\int_0^T f(t,\theta)dB_t.$$

I am looking for conditions that ensure that
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_0^T f(t,\theta)dB_t=\int_0^T \partial_{\theta}f(t,\theta)dB_t$$

In [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82799669.pdf) and [this](http://archive.numdam.org/article/SPS_1982__16__490_0.pdf) article conditions are set in the case in which $f$ is not deterministic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Proposition 1 in the first paper not answer your question?

Comment: @Chaos Did you find an answer?